# Are there any platforms that do not support reentrent mutex's or recursive locks?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, mutex

I'm wondering if my implementation should expect that reentrant mutex's are supported or not. The code is supposed to portable/platform independent. I'm wondering if mutex recursion is common enough that it shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Do you mean recursive acquisition of a critical section?

Comment: Do you mean locking the same mutex multiple times? Or do you mean locking multiple mutexes? Also, are you using pthreads or something else?

Comment: One answer is, "on all platforms". A mutex has a specific meaning. However, you could expand your question, a lot. As others said, what do you mean with "mutex"? Since you talk about platforms, presumably some OS construct. Which? Be more specific or any answer will either be exceedingly vague or possibly answering something totally different from what you want to know.

Comment: I mean recursive I suppose.  I guess thats what all the kids are calling it.

Comment: Well, @Kevin, then the answer is "on all platforms" if you use a mechanism which works like a mutex should: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Comment: pthreads are not necessarily used but are likely.  There is a porting layer defining a mutex interface so the implementation can vary depending on the platform.

Comment: @Michael Yes.  Thats what I mean.

Comment: I'll try editing my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually a distinct option, available through a different function call. Even then it isn't "detected" it's just "permitted".

Sometimes, you WANT the lock to be recursive. Sometimes, you DON'T want the lock to be recursive. Any solution you come up with without explicitly allowing both conditions will not work universally for every mutex solution available without you imposing some contraints that don't exist in the libraries you'll be wrapping.